# Unknown attribute type (Object) for attribute data

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui

JSP Page error. How to solve the "Unknown attribute type (Object) for attribute data." ERROR.
and the error point to 

">
Below is my JSP code.

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="kendo" uri="http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="resources/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />

<script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<%
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("adaf");
    data.add("bdfa");
    data.add("cdasf");
%>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<kendo:dropDownList name="things">
    <kendo:dataSource data="<%=data %>">
    </kendo:dataSource>
</kendo:dropDownList>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ERROR Message:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(32,1) Unknown attribute type (Object) for attribute data.
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:236)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:846)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:865)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1763)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Environment:
Tomcat 6.0
JDK1.7

Comment: there is you servlet code?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I follow the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VH75XVhLCI  There is no servlet~

Comment: What type of data  attribute does the <kendo:dataSource /> tag expect? Maybe something other than a list, which is what you are supplying?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am facing the same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Comment out blocks of code until the error goes away. Then gradually uncomment sections until you zoom into error... Sort of akin to a binary search...

Answer (score 0):

When you place a JSP expression (`<%=data %>`) in you JSP page, it should contain a string. In your case, the Kendo DataSource `data` attribute expects an array.

Try converting `<%=data %>` to a string in the form `["adaf", "bdfa", "cdasf"]` using the following:

```
${fn:join(data, ', ')}
```

Comment: In my case, it's not like that. This is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919247/http-status-500-kendo-jsp19-13-unknown-attribute-type-string-for-attribut

Answer (score 0):

Old version of JAR causing the issue.